# Mesh only visible in reflection

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using a cubeCamera for live cube maps reflections.
How do I show a mesh only in the reflection.

Can anyone guide me how to accomplish it, or is it possible at all ?

```
  cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 1, 600, 512 );
  cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
  scene.add( cubeCamera );
```

**envMap**

envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget,

**Basic mesh**

```
  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 1, 1 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff });

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
scene.add( mesh );
```

**Render**

```
function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

function render() {

  cubeCamera.updateCubeMap( renderer, scene );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

function update() {

  requestAnimationFrame( update );
  render();

}
```

Comment: What does your render loop look like? In your render loop, wouldn't you just make your mesh visible, render the cubeCamera, then make your mesh invisible again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I have not tested it)
I am assuming it is the mesh object that you want only visible in the reflections.

**Basic mesh**

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff });

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
// make your mesh invisible.
mesh.visible = false;
scene.add( mesh );
```

**Render**

```
function render() {
  // Make mesh visible to the cubeCamera.
  mesh.visible = true;
  cubeCamera.updateCubeMap( renderer, scene );
  // Make mesh invisible again.
  mesh.visible = false;
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```